# Using a Class within a Class in Processing

Tags: class, processing

I am trying to create a Processing animation using mass points and springs. I am able to define the mass points, and they work as expected. However when I try to create a spring going between the two mass points the script fails and I am told that "MassPoint is not defined". I am confused because I have defined MassPoint and am using it to create the two points that I already have. Is there a different way that I need to declare it within the Spring class?

```
MassPoint mp1 = new MassPoint(50, 50, 1.0, PI, 3);
MassPoint mp2 = new MassPoint(60, 60, 0, PI, 3);
Spring s1 = new Spring(mp1,mp2,30,1)

// Setup the Processing Canvas
void setup(){
  size(screen.width, screen.height);
  strokeWeight(1);
  stroke(#000000);
  frameRate( 15 );
  background(background_color);
  fill(#FFFFFF,alpha);

}

// Main draw loop
void draw(){
    background(background_color);
    mp1.move();
    mp2.move();
    console.log(mp1.xPos)
}

class MassPoint { 
  int xPos,yPos,mass; 
  float speed,angle;

  MassPoint (int x, int y, float s, float a, int m) {  
    xPos = x; 
    yPos = y;
    speed = s; 
    angle = a;
    mass = m; 
  } 

  void move(){
    xPos += sin(angle) * speed
    yPos -= cos(angle) * speed
    point(xPos,yPos)
  }
}


class Spring { 
  float length,strength;
  MassPoint mp1, mp2;

  Spring (MassPoint mp1, MassPoint mp2, float l, float s) {  
    xPos1 = mp1.xPos; 
    yPos1 = mp1.yPos;
    xPos2 = mp2.xPos; 
    yPos2 = mp2.yPos;
    length = l; 
    strength = s; 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Is the language in use here javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using an earlier version of Processing before 2.0?  Maybe in early versions you were required to declare classes before using them, though it's no longer the case.  To verify this, move all class declarations to the top of the file.

Trying the code in both 2.1.1 and 3.3 gives the error "Change screen.width and screen.height to displayWidth and displayHeight", which suggested an older version.  See information about these changes [here](https://github.com/processing/processing/wiki/Changes).  Also, the call `console.log()` is not defined, use `println()` instead.

Below is my version of the code tested in Processing 2.1.1.  No gravity or damping, but shows interesting spring behavior.

```
MassPoint mpS = new MassPoint(100, 100, 0, PI, 20);
MassPoint mp0 = new MassPoint(100, 100, 0, PI, 20);
MassPoint mp1 = new MassPoint(50,  100, 0, PI, 10);
MassPoint mp2 = new MassPoint(50, 150, 1, PI, 5);
Spring s1 = new Spring(mp0,mp1,50,0.0001);
Spring s2 = new Spring(mp1,mp2,50,0.0001);
int background_color = 64;
int alpha = 255;

// Setup the Processing Canvas
void setup(){
  size(displayWidth, displayHeight);
  strokeWeight(1);
  stroke(#000000);
  //frameRate( 15 );
  background(background_color);
  fill(#FFFFFF,alpha);

}

// Main draw loop
void draw(){
    background(background_color);

    // Spring 0 is static and cannot move
    mp0.xPos = mpS.xPos;
    mp0.yPos = mpS.yPos;

    // Spring 1 and 2 can move
    mp1.move();
    mp2.move();
    s1.move();
    s2.move();

    // Red when compressed, green when stretched
    stroke( constrain(127-4*round(s1.springStretch),0,255), constrain(4*round(s1.springStretch)-127,0,255), 0 );
    line(mp0.xPos, mp0.yPos, mp1.xPos, mp1.yPos);

    stroke( constrain(127-4*round(s2.springStretch),0,255),     constrain(4*round(s2.springStretch)-127,0,255), 0 );
    line(mp1.xPos, mp1.yPos, mp2.xPos, mp2.yPos);

    stroke(0);
    fill(1);
    ellipse(mp0.xPos, mp0.yPos, mp0.mass, mp0.mass);
    ellipse(mp1.xPos, mp1.yPos, mp1.mass, mp1.mass);
    ellipse(mp2.xPos, mp2.yPos, mp2.mass, mp2.mass);

    //println(mp1.xPos);
}

class MassPoint { 
  float xPos,yPos,mass; 
  float xSpeed,ySpeed;

  MassPoint (int x, int y, float s, float a, int m) {  
    xPos = x; 
    yPos = y;
    xSpeed =  (s * sin(a)); 
    ySpeed = -(s * cos(a)); 
    mass = m; 
  } 

  void move(){
    xPos += xSpeed;
    yPos += ySpeed;
    point(xPos,yPos);
  }

  void applyForce( float fx, float fy )
  {
    float x = fx / mass;
    float y = fy / mass;
    xSpeed = xSpeed + x;
    ySpeed = ySpeed + y;
    xPos = xPos + x;
    yPos = yPos + y;
  }
}

class Spring { 
  float springLength, springStrength, springStretch;
  MassPoint mp1, mp2;

  Spring (MassPoint mp1, MassPoint mp2, float l, float s) {  
    this.mp1 = mp1;
    this.mp2 = mp2;
    springLength = l; 
    springStrength = s; 
    springStretch = 0;
  } 
  void move(){
    float xDelta = mp2.xPos - mp1.xPos;
    float yDelta = mp2.yPos - mp1.yPos;
    float dist = sqrt( (xDelta*xDelta) + (yDelta*yDelta) );
    springStretch = (dist-springLength);
    float power = springStretch * springStrength;
    mp1.applyForce(  xDelta*power,  yDelta*power );
    mp2.applyForce( -xDelta*power, -yDelta*power );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This code works for my version of processing. Though it seems like I may want to update it at some point!

Answer (score 0):

Are you porting from JavaScript or something? that's a weird hybrid you have there. See if this helps.

```
MassPoint mp1 = new MassPoint(50, 50, 1.0, PI, 3);
MassPoint mp2 = new MassPoint(60, 60, 0, PI, 3);
Spring s1 = new Spring(mp1,mp2,30,1);

// Setup the Processing Canvas
void setup(){
  size(600, 400);
  strokeWeight(1);
  stroke(#000000);
  frameRate( 15 );
  background(0);
  fill(#FFFFFF);

}

// Main draw loop
void draw(){
    background(0);
    mp1.move();
    mp2.move();
    println(mp1.yPos);
}

class MassPoint { 
  int xPos,yPos,mass; 
  float speed,angle;

  MassPoint (int x, int y, float s, float a, int m) {  
    xPos = x; 
    yPos = y;
    speed = s; 
    angle = a;
    mass = m; 
  } 

  void move(){
    xPos += sin(angle) * speed;
    yPos -= cos(angle) * speed;
    point(xPos,yPos);
  }
}


class Spring { 
  float length,strength;
  float xPos1, yPos1, xPos2, yPos2;
  MassPoint mp1, mp2;

  Spring (MassPoint mp1, MassPoint mp2, float l, float s) {  
    xPos1 = mp1.xPos; 
    yPos1 = mp1.yPos;
    xPos2 = mp2.xPos; 
    yPos2 = mp2.yPos;
    length = l; 
    strength = s; 
  } 
}
```